# SQL Server guy working with PostgreSQL now, failing to create simple stored procedure - error Unterminated dollar quote

Tags: postgresql, heidisql

I am starting out with PostgreSQL and have realised that while working with C# and EF Core I have a set of logic that would work better in a stored procedure in the database. However I've come from a SQL Server background, so writing PL/pgSQL is a whole new ball game to me. I'm trying to create a test procedure below that just takes a string, adds some letters to it, and returns it. But it fails with the error shown in the screenshot. I can't really work out how to resolve this, or even what it's really pointing to. Can anyone assist?

[image]

Comment: Your SQL client doesn't understand dollar quoting. You will have to use standard SQL quotes (and escaping embedded single quotes by doubling them)

Answer (score 0):

Your (unspecified) client software is not hip to PostgreSQL syntax and thinks that the first best semicolon terminates a statement. Use something else.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. Am using HeidiSQL which supposedly supports PostgreSQL. Well there you go!

Comment: Yes HeidiSQL is known for this problem.